# Need help separating individual integers withing a fraction

Tags: java

I have a Fractional Calculator project I'm trying out. I've figured out how to do everything in terms of operations, but I am still struggling to REDUCE the fraction answers that my code gives me. I have an idea of what I need to do in terms of the Euclidian algorithm, but I need to have two integers for that. I know what the integers are, but I can't isolate them to plug into a 2-integer method and then print them out as a fraction.

My main class:

```
    package fracCalc;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    // @KashyapGarimella
    // Period 2
    // CP 3
    // FracCalc
    public class FracCalc {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Input an equation: ");
            String input = console.nextLine();
            while (!input.equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println(produceAnswer(input));
                System.out.println("Input another equation: ");
                input = console.nextLine();
                } 
            System.out.println("End.");
            console.close();
        }
        public static String produceAnswer(String input) {
            Scanner token = new Scanner(input);
            String operator_1 = token.next();
            String function = token.next();
            String operator_2 = token.next();
            token.close();
            Fraction fraction_1 = Fraction.Improper (parse(operator_1));
            Fraction fraction_2 = Fraction.Improper (parse(operator_2));
            Fraction answer = solveEquation(fraction_1, function, fraction_2);
            return (answ

er.Numerator + "/" + answer.Denominator);
    }
    public static Fraction parse(String input) {
        Fraction fraction = new Fraction();
        if(input.indexOf("_")> 0){
            fraction.Integer = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, input.indexOf("_")));
            fraction.Numerator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.indexOf("_") + 1, input.indexOf("/")));
            fraction.Denominator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.indexOf("/") + 1));
        }
        else if (input.indexOf("/") > 0) {
            fraction.Numerator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, input.indexOf("/")));
            fraction.Denominator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.indexOf("/") + 1));
        } else {
            fraction.Integer = Integer.parseInt (input);

        }
        return fraction;
    }
    public static Fraction solveEquation (Fraction fraction_1, String function, Fraction fraction_2){
        Fraction fraction = new Fraction();
        if (function.equals("+")){
            fraction.Numerator = fraction_1.Numerator * fraction_2.Denominator + fraction_1.Denominator * fraction_2.Numerator;
            fraction.Denominator = fraction_1.Denominator * fraction_2.Denominator;
        }
        else if (function.equals("-")) {
            fraction.Numerator = fraction_1.Numerator * fraction_2.Denominator - fraction_1.Denominator*fraction_2.Numerator;
            fraction.Denominator = fraction_1.Denominator * fraction_2.Denominator;
        }
        else if (function.equals("*")) {
            fraction.Numerator = fraction_1.Numerator * fraction_2.Numerator;
            fraction.Denominator = fraction_1.Denominator * fraction_2.Denominator;
        }
        else if (function.equals("/")) {
            fraction.Numerator = fraction_1.Numerator * fraction_2.Denominator;
            fraction.Denominator = fraction_1.Denominator * fraction_2.Numerator;
        }

        return fraction;
    }

}
```

Here is my Fraction class where I intend to host the Euclidian algorithm.

```
package fracCalc;

public class Fraction {
    int Numerator = 0;
    int Denominator = 1;
    int Integer = 0;


public static Fraction Improper(Fraction improper){
    Fraction fraction = new Fraction();
    fraction.Denominator = improper.Denominator;
    if(improper.Integer < 0){
        fraction.Numerator = improper.Integer * improper.Denominator + (-1) * improper.Numerator;
        }
    else {
    fraction.Numerator = improper.Integer * improper.Denominator + improper.Numerator;
    }
    return fraction;
} 
}
```

Comment: Are you asking, how to apply the eucidian algorithm to reducing fractions?

Comment: Not really, I just wanted to figure out how to separate the two integers that currently make up my fractional answer and plug those in to the GCD method to return a Fraction type answer to my produceAnswer method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will clearly need to calculate the  Greatest Common Denominator(GCD) between the numerator and the denominator. You can achieve this as follows, where p is the numerator and q is the denominator.

```
public static int getGCD(int p, int q) {
    while (q != 0) {
        int temp = q;
        q = p % q;
        p = temp;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Now that you calculated the GCD, all you then need to do is divide both the numerator and denominator this number, thus giving you the most reduced form of the fraction.

Update:
Your produceAnswer function is probably the source of your error. Try making a function that takes a string as input and creates a fraction object by checking through each character in the string until '/' is found. At this point you can isolate both the numerator and denominator, and assign them to this fraction object that you will then return.

Once you have this completed, you can simply change your produceAnswer function to take in a fraction object, and easily access the data you need.

Comment: Hey, Shane. Thanks for the code, but how do I go about separating the two integers that make up the numerator and the denominator to get ints p and q? Right now they are in a type I called Fraction(the class) and I want this method to return a fraction type to my produceAnswer method in my main code.